# Android splash screen, opaque background not working

Tags: android, transparent, splash-screen

I'm trying to get the background of my splash screen to be opaque/transparent. I made a colors.xml in values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="translucent_black">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

Then I have my splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/translucent_black">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I feel like I should have something in the manifest, but I keep getting errors putting activitys in. Also if you are really feeling frisky, I can figure out how to make the title bar go away either. Thanks again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Simple Method**

Specify the activity to use the translucent theme (in manifest.xml):

```
<activity ... 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" 
          .../>
```

**Advanced Method**

If you want more customisability you can create your own theme extending the Translucent theme (manifest.xml):

```
<activity ... 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.MyTranslucentTheme"
          .../>
```

and in styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="MyTranslucentTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_black</item>
</style>

<color name="transparent_black">#DA000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! It's asking for an attribute name, should I call it anything special?

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
<
activity
...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" 

....../>
```

you have to extend `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` in `Activity.class` inheritance.